# Resize an iframe to fit within another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to add an iframe (of one page on my site) to another page of my site.  I've figured out the code for the iframe and used div to take a portion of it.  Now I'd like to shrink the entire webpage (within the iframe) to fit within the page I'm adding it to.  How do I change the following code to do that?

```
<div style="border:0; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.tryary.com/forums/topic/21/best-law-of-attraction-books/post-create?" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -0px; height: 1000px; margin-top: -333px; width: 726px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please attach some code to your question. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the code of that page. It's hard, if not impossible, to answer the question like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to fit the size of the iframe then check this below code in html

**HTML**

```
<div id="output" style="width:500px;height:400px;">
    <iframe src="www.google.com" style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="ifrm"></iframe>
</div>
```

If you want the content also to be shrinked, then use the css transform as below

**CSS**

```
#ifrm {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```